# Uncheck other checkbox on checked flutter

Tags: flutter, checkbox

I have three checkboxes (lets the user chose different difficulty). Right now the checkboxes are all clickable.

But for obvious reason I only want the user to be able to chose one difficulty at the time- why I'm trying to get every other box unchecked for every new click.

After the user has chosen the difficulty he will be able to make another choice. When that choice is made he will automatically be directed to an other page. (In other words- the checkbox choice is unimportant until the user makes his second choice).

I tried something like

```
void checkBoxes() {
    if (_value1 = true) {
      _value2 = false;
      _value3 = false;
    } else if (_value2 = true) {
      _value1 = false;
      _value3 = false;
    } else if (_value3 = true) {
      _value1 = false;
      _value2 = false;
    }
  }
```

But no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take change state of another variables on click of checkbox in onChanged() method
and assign that value to checkbox widget such as below:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    ));

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool valMonday = false;
  bool valTuesday = false;
  bool valWednesday = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Group Checkboxes"),
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[

              // [Monday] checkbox
              Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text("Monday"),
                  Checkbox(
                    value: valMonday,
                    onChanged: (bool value) {
                      setState(() {
                        valMonday = value;
                        valTuesday = false;
                        valWednesday = false;
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),


              // [Tuesday] checkbox
              Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text("Tuesday"),
                  Checkbox(
                    value: valTuesday,
                    onChanged: (bool value) {
                      setState(() {
                        valTuesday = value;
                        valMonday = false;
                        valWednesday = false;
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),


              // [Wednesday] checkbox
              Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text("Wednesday"),
                  Checkbox(
                    value: valWednesday,
                    onChanged: (bool value) {
                      setState(() {
                        valWednesday = value;
                        valMonday = false;
                        valTuesday = false;
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch :)